# AD LDS query fails to get second page of large number of groups

Tags: ad-lds

We hit the 1015 limit in AD DS, so we are exploring AD LDS as an alternative. To test the limit, I've created >32,000 groups, each nested inside another, with my user in the top and bottom level group. This query works for the first page, but fails to return the second.

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=jdentler,cn=adfsteststore,dc=local))
```

I've set size limit = 0 and page size = 900 and the search type to subtree.

LDP returns this:

```
   -=>> 'Run' for more, 'Close' to abandon <<=-
0x1 = ldap_get_next_page_s(ld, hPage, 900, &timeout, 0, 0x3712DB8);
Server error: 000020EF: SvcErr: DSID-02080127, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data -1601

Error 0x20EF The directory service encountered an unknown failure.
ldap_search_abandon_page(ld, hPage)
Result <1>: 000020EF: SvcErr: DSID-02080127, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data -1601
```